# Spring Embedded solr

Tags: java, spring, solr

I am creating beans for embedded Solr for testing in Junit like this :

```
@Bean(name = "solrServer")
public SolrClient solrServerFactoryBean() {
    EmbeddedSolrServerFactory factory = new EmbeddedSolrServerFactoryBean();
    factory.setSolrHome("classpath:solr");
    return factory.getSolrClient("xx");
}

/**
 * Initiate SolrTemplate bean.
 *
 * @return {@link SolrTemplate}
 * @throws Exception throws exception when error occurs when creating SolrTemplate bean.
 */
@Bean
public SolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new SolrTemplate(solrServerFactoryBean());
}
```

But when i running the application it showing me error:

Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/dev/project-service/target/test-classes/solr

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Having the issue. Have you found a solution/resolution ?

Comment: Can you post, what are the dependencies and versions you are using?